# Does Facebook use a reverse proxy per IP?

Tags: facebook, caching, refresh, counter

My final aim is to get the like count for a FaceBook PAGE. In short, I was doing
curl "https://fr-fr.facebook.com/PAGE/" | heavy-sed

Then, I found this page is much lighter, and saves bandwidth:
"https://fr-fr.facebook.com/PAGE/about"

Because of some bug, I have gone a bit further, and tried the more advanced method:
"https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE?access_token=secret|id&fields=fan_count"

All three methods end up in the same issue: the value returned by curl|sed always remain the same for a few hours (3 to 6h), even when the value is updated on classic browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

Many projects claim to update every 10s without issue. FB API states I should be allowed to do 200 requests per hour. Adding to curl -A with the same UA as my firefox does not help.

I do not personally have any Facebook account; so, even when I am using Firefox or Chrome, I am viewing a public page with anonymous access. Facebook should not be able to make any difference between curl and firefox when I provide the same UA.

I really need fresh values; 60 calls per hour is far below the official limit; one call every minute is enough for my project; but a 3h latency is not.

Curl is using IPv4 access, while Firefox is using IPv6; so, if Facebook is using a reverse proxy per IP, I would not be able to proove/detect it.

I do not understand why Firefox/Chrome can obtain a fresh and up to date value, while curl -A obtains a deprecated result.

Comment: _“Facebook should not be able to make any difference between curl and firefox when I provide the same UA”_ - they still are; if not with the initial request, then at the latest when an actual user starts interacting with the page. But since you are not allowed to scrape Facebook URLs directly, this point is moot anyway. You have to use the API (or make do with the official Like button plugin, that shows the current like count automatically.)

Comment: Is there an other API than "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE?access_token=secret|id&fields=fan_count" ?